# How to enable Azure CDN for Azure storage blob static website?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

After enabling static website on Azure storage, I have deployed an index.html to the `$web` blob container. `https://<name>.<zone>.web.core.windows.net` works fine.

To add custom domain with HTTPS support, it is [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#custom-domain-names) that we use `Azure CDN` to access the blobs. On the [linked page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn) to enable that, the page says

> During preview of static websites support in Azure Storage, select "custom origin" from the "origin type" drop down menu to add your storage web endpoint. In Azure Portal, you will need to do this from your CDN Profile instead of directly in your storage account.

So I selected `Custom Origin` as the origin type and made `<name>.<zone>.web.core.windows.net` as the origin hostname.

However, trying to access `https://<cdnendpointname>.azureedge.net/` is sending me to `404 Not Found` page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like it was a propagation issue. The CDN endpoint started working fine after 30 mins.

Comment: Probably, you should mark your answer as accepted. The info in the question is really useful and this answer complements it well by providing info on the gotcha.